# Unable to connect Apps Script to Cloud SQL using JDBC

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

So... I have been trying to set up the connection to a Cloud SQL for MySQL database from an Apps Script function, however I am unable to figure out why it is not working. I have been following the [documentation for JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc), however no matter what I do, the connection always fails.

The following is the code I am using:

```js
const connectionName = '<project_id>:<region>:<instance_id>';
const user = '<user>';
const userPwd = '<user_pass>';
const db = '<database>';

const dbUrl = 'jdbc:google:mysql://' + connectionName + '/' + db;

function connect() {
  const conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  let start = new Date();
  let stmt = conn.createStatement();

  stmt.setMaxRows(1000);

  let results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM entries');
  let numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

  while (results.next()) {
    let rowString = '';
    for (let col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
    }
    Logger.log(rowString);
  }

  results.close();
  stmt.close();

  let end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms', end - start);
}
```

When running this code I get the following error:

[image]

Every time I run the code, I can see a new line in the mysqlerr logs:

[image]

I have the Cloud SQL instance set with the public IP, but I have not whitelisted any networks. The documentation does not mention it as a required step. Also I have set the project number for the GCP project of this Apps Script project, but still I get this error.

**EDIT**

As requested, I am adding more screenshots about the instance:

I am able to connect to the Cloud SQL instance using the `gcloud sql instances connect` command, and once inside I am able to query the table I want. (Bear in mind that the table is currently empty, as we are in the early stages of development at this point)

I believe this rules out the possibility of me using the wrong user/password.

[image]

As you can see I am using the default value for the `max_allowed_packet` flag. To be honest I have not set any flags on this instance yet.

About the connection name, I am using the format shared in the code snippet above, and actually I have copy and pasted it from the Cloud Console.

The next screenshot is the summary of the instance's settings:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I work on the team that maintains Google Cloud SQL Connector libraries.

I was able to get your code sample working with my own project, so I don't think your code is the problem. The first thing I would try is double checking the values of user, userPwd, and connectionName. If those are all correct, then I would also ensure that the user you are trying to log in as has access to the database.

As for those errors you're seeing in the logs, this [troubleshooting documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/error-messages#operations-errors) has some suggestions regarding things you can try. Once suggestion would be to increase the [`max_allowed_packet`](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags) flag

If you're sure that all of those values are correct, then please follow up to this comment and we can try to debug further.

Comment: Hi @Shubha Rajan, thank you for your answer. I have added the requested information to my Question

Comment: I dug into this a little more and found this old issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/36755580
Apps Script uses the user credentials of the user running the program to connect. So if you're running the script as a user who doesn't have Cloud SQL client permissions on that project, you'll get an error. Are you running the script while logged in as a user with permissions to access that Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: Hi @Shubha Rajan, sorry for the delay. Yes, I also saw that recommendation, unfortunately I have already tried this. The user I am using to trigger the script has both the "Project Owner" and "Cloud SQL Client" roles.